# Plus button displaying results in a half screen in simulator

Tags: swift, swiftui

When the plus button is pressed. I'm able to write my text but when I click "add" it displays it on a half screen on the bottom half of my simulator. I would like to know if anybody could help me make the text just show on the UI.

This is my results right now:

[image: Demo]

My code.

```
struct LandingView: View {

    @State private var newLandingName: String = ""
    @State private var isAddingLanding = false
    @State private var landings: [String] = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
                Circle()
                    .scale(1.7)
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow.opacity(0.60))
                Circle()
                    .scale(1.3)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue.opacity(0.50))

                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Add Your Travels")
                            .bold()
                            .alignmentGuide(.leading) { _ in 0 }
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                            .alignmentGuide(.top) { _ in 0 }
                            .padding()
                        Spacer()
                        ZStack {
                            GeometryReader { geometry in
                                Button(action: {
                                    isAddingLanding = true
                                }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                .position(x: geometry.size.width - 30, y: 30)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    }
                    List(landings, id: \.self) { landing in Text(landing)

                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landings!"))
                }
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isAddingLanding, onDismiss: {}) {
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Where did you go? \(newLandingName)", text: $newLandingName)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .padding()
                        Button("Add") {
                            if !newLandingName.isEmpty {
                                landings.append(newLandingName)
                                newLandingName = ""
                            }
                            isAddingLanding = false
                        }
                        Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I've tried moving the snippets around but no results, still get the half screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

1. You use `.frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)` on the headline which makes it use all available height space. `List` itself also tries to use all available height space, which in combination leads to a 50/50 division of heights of these two elements.
2. List with no further specification has an opaque background, so you don't see your UI behind it.

Solution: Get rid of `.frame()` on the headline and use modifiers on `List` to make it transparent.

You also don't need `GeometryReader` or `AlignmentGuide`, at least not in the code you shared ... so I eliminated those and optimised some other parts.

Here is your cleaned code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var newLandingName: String = ""
    @State private var isAddingLanding = false
    @State private var landings: [String] = ["Tampa", "JFK"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                
                // first Layer: Color cirlces
                Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
                Circle()
                    .scale(1.7)
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow.opacity(0.60))
                Circle()
                    .scale(1.3)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue.opacity(0.50))
                
                // second layer: Text
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Add Your Travels")
                            .bold()
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            isAddingLanding = true
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    
                    List(landings, id: \.self) { landing in
                        Text(landing).bold()
                            .foregroundColor(.white) // text color
                            .listRowBackground(Color.clear) // make list transparent
                            .listRowSeparatorTint(.white) // color of separator lines
                    }
                    .listStyle(.plain) // make list transparent
                }
                
            } // end of ZStack
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landings!"))
            
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isAddingLanding, onDismiss: {}) {
                VStack {
                    TextField("Where did you go? \(newLandingName)", text: $newLandingName)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding()
                    Button("Add") {
                        if !newLandingName.isEmpty {
                            landings.append(newLandingName)
                            newLandingName = ""
                        }
                        isAddingLanding = false
                    }
                    Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```